Remove access to Email Messages for User Profile
Issue: we want to remove access to all Email Messages for a specific User Profile.
One set of Users, where Profile = Rep, add their email messages from Outlook to Salesforce by tagging the Contact in the Salesforce for Outlook pane. The client has a User record, where Profile = Client, that can access the emails where their related Contact is tagged. We don't want the client's related User record to have access to the Emails.
Is it possible to remove access to Email objects for a specific User Profile?
